# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at getCountry (Country.js:8:1) at Country.js:13:1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

i need  a help with one fetch issue that i'm facing.

I did create a JS function to read a country.json that I did insert inside of my wampserver "www/data_api/country.json". The server it's online, and when access it diretcly using the link (http://localhost/data_api/country) works fine.

The problem it's when i call this link in my async function. Below my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Country() {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);

    useEffect( ()=>{
        const getCountry = async ()=>{
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost/data_api/country.json");
            const getcon = await res.json();
            console.log(getcon);
            setCountry(await getcon);
        }
        getCountry();
    },[]);

  return (
    <div>Country</div>
  )
}

export default Country
```

And the message that i'm receiving it's:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at getCountry (Country.js:8:1)
    at Country.js:13:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26935:1)
```

I'm expecting to see in the console.log the all contries in objects.

Comment: Sidenote: `setCountry(await getcon);` <-- that makes no sense why there is an await there.

Comment: what do you see in the network panel?

Comment: I'm seeing now this error: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/data_api/country.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Solution, do not use a hard coded path so it used the port. `fetch("/data_api/country.json");` You do not want to hardcode the domain portion because what happens when you push this out to production? It will point to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, and see the error logged on the console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Country() {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);

    useEffect( ()=>{
        const getCountry = async ()=>{
          try{
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost/data_api/country.json");
            const getcon = await res.json();
            console.log(getcon);
            setCountry(  getcon);
            }catch(error){
              console.log('An error occured')
              console.log(error)
          }

        }
        getCountry();
    },[]);

  return (
    <div>Country</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Console message:An error occured
Country.js:39 TypeError: Failed to fetch

May be the issue it's here?
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Comment: Try this url as an endpoint:
https://restcountries.com/v2/all
and make sure that your endpoint (http://localhost/data_api/country.json) returns a valid json response.

Comment: did work now, maybe it's some internal restriction in my local server?

Comment: Ah okay, you can install this chrome extension to disable cors temporarily https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en